# Python 3: `netloc` value in `urllib.parse` is empty if URL doesn't have `//`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I notice that `netloc` is empty if the URL doesn't have `//`.

**Without `//`, `netloc` is empty**

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('google.com')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='google.com', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>>
>>> urlparse('www.google.com')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.google.com', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>>
>>> urlparse('google.com/search?q=python')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='google.com/search', params='', query='q=python', fragment='')
>>>
```

**With `//`, `netloc` is identified correctly**

```
>>> urlparse('http://google.com')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>>
>>> urlparse('//google.com')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='google.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>>
>>> urlparse('http://google.com/search?q=python')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.com', path='/search', params='', query='q=python', fragment='')
>>>
```

Would it be possible to identify `netloc` correctly even if `//` not provided in the URL?

Answer (score 7):

> Would it be possible to identify netloc correctly even if // not provided in the URL?

Not by using `urlparse`. This is explicitly explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlparse#urllib.parse.urlparse):

> Following the syntax specifications in RFC 1808, urlparse recognizes a `netloc` only if it is properly introduced by `//`. Otherwise the input is presumed to be a relative URL and thus to start with a path component.

If you don't want to rewrite `urlparse`'s logic (which I would not suggest), make sure `url` starts with `//`:

```
if not url.startswith('//'):
    url = '//' + url
```

**EDIT**

The above is actually a bad solution as @alexis noted. Perhaps

```
if not (url.startswith('//') or url.startswith('http://') or url.startswith('https://')):
    url = '//' + url
```

But your mileage may very with that solution as well. If you have to support a wide variety of inconsistent formats you may have to resort to regex.

Comment: Thanks ... Is there any alternative or workaround for this?

Comment: @Sabrina I edited the answer. It is pretty straightforward

Comment: That edit is a little aggressive... you'll end up with `'//http://google.com'` if you don't rein it in :,-)

Comment: Please, either write one regular expression or just check for `"//" in url` (which will match it anywhere, of course). And why have both a wrong and an improved solution? Just edit and fix the answer, I won't mind if my comment no longer makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an application that needs to parse out the scheme and netloc from a URL that might not have any scheme set. I've settled on this approach, although it is smelly and I doubt it will handle every corner case either.

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Dec  3 2019, 17:33:19)
[GCC 9.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> url="google.com"
>>> o = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
>>> u = urllib.parse.SplitResult(
...     scheme=o.scheme if o.scheme else "https",
...     netloc=o.netloc if o.netloc else o.path,
...     path="",
...     query="",
...     fragment=""
... )
>>> urllib.parse.urlunsplit(u)
'https://google.com'
>>>
```

Comment: if the actual url contains path, query, and fragment then you are brute forcing it to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like that:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, ParseResult

def createParser(url: str, default_scheme = 'https') -> ParseResult:
    url = url.strip().strip('/')
    parser = urlparse(url)

    if not parser.netloc:
        parser = createParser(f'{default_scheme}://{url}')

    return parser

parser: ParseResult = createParser('stackoverflow.com/questions/53816559')
print(parser) # ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='stackoverflow.com', path='/questions/53816559', params='', query='', fragment='')

parser2: ParseResult = createParser('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816559')
print(parser2) # ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='stackoverflow.com', path='/questions/53816559', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

No need to import `ParseResult`. I don't know how to explain this code, but it works.

If you give an URL that have no scheme, or doesn't start with an `//`, it will add and default schema to the URL and restart the process